# SQL to make new column(mySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I got two sql statements:

```
SELECT username AS userA FROM WHERE username='abc'
SELECT username AS userB FROM WHERE username='abcd' AND password='abcd'
```

I want to output the result as below:

```
userA  |  userB
----------------
abc    |  abcd
```

How to combine two SQL statements?

Comment: I don't think you can join them like that. The closest I know of is a union, which will select them as two rows instead of two columns.

Comment: Why are you selecting the username when you already know what it is?  (The value is in the `where` clause.)

Comment: Can you provide us with some table structure?  The easiest way to handle this would be to _join_ the two tables together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tableA.username as userA
    tableB.username as userB
FROM tableA
CROSS JOIN table B
WHERE tableA.username='abc'
    AND tableB.username='abcd'
    AND tableB.password='abcd';
```

CROSS JOIN!  :P CARTESIAN PRODUCT!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine tables and fields with the syntax:

```
SELECT tableA.username as userA
    tableB.username as userB
FROM tableA
JOIN table B
WHERE tableA.username='abc'
    AND tableB.username='abcd'
    AND tableB.password='abcd';
```

Unless there's some kind of relation between the tables, you'll be getting the cross product times rows, so it might be an NxM result which is just useless.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't try it but here something you can try:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT username AS userA FROM WHERE username='abc' LIMIT 1) AS 'userA',
  (SELECT username AS userB FROM WHERE username='abcd' AND password='abcd' LIMIT 1) AS 'userB';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select t1.userA,t2.userB  
 from
      (SELECT username AS userA FROM WHERE username='abc')t1
 join (SELECT username AS userB FROM WHERE username='abcd' AND password='abcd')t2
 where 1=1
```

where 1=1 will combine any 2 queries without condition but it's meaningless. Although it match what you asked i don't suggest people use it